# Angular momentum conservation in $e^-_{\text{R}}e^+_{\text{L}}\rightarrow\mu^-_{\text{R}}\mu^+_{\text{L}}$ scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering

In Peskin and Schroeder section 5.2, the cross section for $e^-_{\text{R}}e^+_{\text{L}}\rightarrow\mu^-_{\text{R}}\mu^+_{\text{L}}$ scattering in the high energy limit is derived. I have no problem with the calculation; the result is

> $$
> \frac{\text{d}\sigma}{\text{d}\Omega}(e^-_{\text{R}}e^+_{\text{L}}\rightarrow\mu^-_{\text{R}}\mu^+_{\text{L}}) = \frac{\alpha^2}{4E_{\text{cm}}^2}(1+\cos\theta)^2.\tag{5.22}
> $$

What I am confused by is the following statement:

> Note that the cross section (5.22) for $e^-_{\text{R}}e^+_{\text{L}}\rightarrow\mu^-_{\text{R}}\mu^+_{\text{L}}$ vanishes at $\theta = 180^\circ$. This is just what we would expect, since for $\theta = 180^\circ$, the total angular momentum of the final state is opposite to that of the initial state.

This is probably a very basic question, but how is it possible to know what the angular momentum of the incoming and outgoing states is? The momentum and total angular momentum operators do not commute, so surely they cannot be known simultaneously?

Comment: I think P&S are talking about helicity in this context. Helicity commutes with $P$.

Comment: That may be the case, but why would we expect helicity to be conserved? I thought that it was only the sum of helicity and orbital angular momentum that was conserved; the latter does not commute with $P$.

Comment: Helicity is [conserved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirality_(physics)#Chirality_and_helicity) but not Lorentz invariant for massive particles; think of the leptons involved as very energetic, and go to the center of momentum frame. If it makes you uncomfortable, think angular momenta with their z-axes along the direction of motion, and apply your rotation matrices! It should be trivial.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! Just to clarify, the orbital angular momentum doesn't play a role in their argument then?

Comment: I don't understand the "orbital" bit. It is all spin, half and half integral, adding up to 1, that of the photon, whose projection to opposite itself is zero,  $^1_{1,1}$=(1+cos)/2 in the amp, so squared in the cross section.

Comment: I mean that when I hear 'total angular momentum', I think of the total angular momentum operator, e.g. for free fermions $\mathbf{J} = \int\text{d}^3 x\,\psi^\dagger\left(\mathbf{x}\times(-i\nabla)+\frac{1}{2}\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)\psi$. This is the sum of the spin and orbital angular momenta. I suppose what I was really asking is: does the argument that P&S give have anything to do with this operator, or are they *only* talking about helicity?

Comment: J=Σ/2 here, is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yep I think so, why is that the case? I.e. what has happened to the $\mathbf{x}\times(-i\nabla)$ part?

Comment: I still do not think this question has anything to do with helicity. Peskin is considering the total angular momentum all the time. The question is that since $J$ and $P$ generally do not commute how come one can get a simultaneous eigenstate of them. However, the original state is a perfect example, it is an eigenstate of $J_z$ and $P$. Because $[J,P]\propto P$ and the $P$ is zero here!

Comment: But I have my question. I can understand from this viewpoint that when $\theta=\pi$ the amplitude vanishes. I cannot extend this argument to general $\theta$ values. How can I prove that the angular momentum in $z$ direction is conserved for all $\theta$?

Comment: A comment for previous comments, in this case, there is no orbital angular momentum. Explained in Peksin under Eq. (5.37).

Comment: The comment under (5.37) relies on the cross section having no angular dependence, which is true in the nonrelativistic limit, but not for the high energy limit. This suggests that the muons do have orbital angular momentum - as you say in your second comment, I don't see how total angular momentum can be conserved for all angles if they only possess only helicity angular momentum.

Comment: So you are suggesting that include orbital angular momentum in the relativistic case to cure my question. This is a good idea. I thought the orbital angular momentum is zero in relativistic cases just as in nonrelativistic cases.